# Сравнение значений ячеек / оптимизация кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, оптимизация, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename="index.xlsx")

print(wb.sheetnames)

wb.active = 0

sheet = wb.active
a = (sheet['A1'].value)
b = (sheet['B1'].value)
c = (sheet['C1'].value)
d = (sheet['D1'].value)
e = (sheet['E1'].value)
f = (sheet['F1'].value)
g = (sheet['G1'].value)
h = (sheet['H1'].value)
i = (sheet['I1'].value)
j = (sheet['J1'].value)

l1 = sheet['L1']
if a < b < c < d < e < f < g < h < i < j:
    l1.value = "1"
else:
    l1.value = "0"


wb.save("D:\\Works\\Python\\Piotrowski index\\index.xlsx")
```

Написал код. Искал различные варианты оптимизации, т.к. нужно будет сравнивать минимум 90 ячеек.

Как более оптимально выполнить сранение ячеек?

Comment: у вас строка всегда одна будет или их может быть много? Можете выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник воспроизводимый пример исходного Excel файла и файл, который вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: Будет 10 строк и 9 столбцов.(на одну из 7000 компаний) Я хочу считать с помощью пайтона "Индекс Пиотровски" (https://smart-lab.ru/blog/55893.php). То есть  каждая компания будет получать баллы (от 1 до 9). Позже я буду суммировать баллы и искать самые рентабельные компании.  Десять строк используется т.к. есть информация за 10 лет.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с использованием модуля Pandas:

Пусть у нас есть сдедующий Excel файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решение:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

filename = "index.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)

df["new"] = df.diff(axis=1).fillna(1).gt(0).all(axis=1).astype(int)

df.to_excel(r"c:\temp\result.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Undefined variable 'filename' попробовал этот код, он выдает ошибку, помогите пожалуйста решить, спасибо

Comment: @Niumandzi, очевидно в эту переменную надо подставить путь к файлу